# Many-to-many connection and Associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord, polymorphic-associations

A User can Upload a Clip via the `Clips Scaffold`, this clip either belongs to a `Show` and or an `Album` (Show Controller, Album Controller).

**A user can have**

- ONLY ONE SHOW
- MANY ALBUMS

  What i'm trying to accomplish:

A **User** can Upload **Clips**, these clips can be attached to either a **Show** or/and an **Album**

For a more detailed overview take a look at the image below:
[image]

**Problem #1** What i'm not understanding is the associations i must use. My current Models:

*User Model*:

```
has_many :clips, dependent: :destroy
has_one :show, dependent: :destroy
has_many :albums, dependent :destroy
```

*Clip Model*: `belongs_to :user`

*Show Model*: `belongs_to :user`

*Album Model*: `belongs_to :user`

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

**Problem #2** I'm not sure on how to accomplish, that when a user uploads a Clip, he can attach (or assign) it to a Show or Album.

What i did with the **Show** (because there is only one) was just to call <%= @user.clip %> on the View Page.

**That means that every clip a user upload's appears on the Show.**

**Which is wrong...**

Now that i have a **Show** AND an **Album** i must grand the user the ability to **choose** where to attach it (On one of the many albums he have, or his Show).

Or should i go with a solution where the User can Upload a Clip THROUGH the **Albums** or **Show** controller (not through the separate **Clips Controller**)

**I really could need some help here :)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem #1 is a textbook case of polymorphic association.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one         :show,
                  :dependent => :destroy
  has_many        :clips,
                  :dependent => :destroy
  has_many        :albums,
                  :dependent => :destroy
end

class Clip < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to      :user
  belongs_to      :attachable,
                  :polymorphic => true
end

class Show < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to      :user
  has_many        :clips,
                  :as => :attachable
end

class Album < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to      :user
  has_many        :clips,
                  :as => :attachable
end
```

You can learn more about polymorphic associations at [Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations).

Now for your problem #2, assuming you do your migrations as per the guide linked above you'll have two database fields in your `clips` table:

- `attachable_id` - This is the `id` of the instance of `Show` or `Album` that's going to receive the association.
- `attachable_type` - This is the class name of the target object, so either `Show` or `Album`.

In your upload form, you're going to show a list of shows and/or albums and assign the `id` to `attachable_id` and the class name to `attachable_type`.

I would suggest loading up your initial select with only one class and then replacing its contents via JavaScript in case the user selects the second option. Like so:

```
<%= f.collection_select :attachable_type, [['Show'], ['Album']], :first, :first, { :selected => 'Show' }, { :include_blank => false } %>
<%= f.collection_select :attachable_id, Show.all, :id, :name %>
```

Comment: That sounds really right :), That's Problem #1, the associations. The ones you provided are really accurate and right. Thank you. Problem #2 is actually HOW TO ASSIGN the clip (when a user uploads) to the show or a specific Album. That means the CODE (f.select e.g.),

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean by *how to assign* the clip, but I tried to answer it in my updated answer. If you still have issues with that, could you be more specific?

Comment: Sorry, i mean the actual code in my _form.html.erb File. The Form for uploading Clips. How can the user choose in which album this clip belongs, or in a Show. There must be some f.select (or something like that) for him to choose among his Albums, or his Show.

Comment: Ugh.. i THINK i understood what you are telling me, but i'm not really getting it. Could you Explain the migration i have to do for the attachable_type. rails g migration AddAttachableTypeToClips attachable_type:string ?

Comment: For the actual migration, please look up the Rails Guides page that I linked to. I could post it in my answer, but I would be simply copying it from the documentation.

Comment: Thank you very much for so much info. I will go through this and try to learn it well. Thanks

Comment: Ok, so i'm stuck at the migration (pardon me, i'm just getting in to this) So Actually i run *rails g migration AddAttachableTypeIDToCLips attachable_type:string attachable_id:integer* and the change my migration File to this -> http://pastebin.com/Ah0zhVNd. Is this Correct ?

Comment: That works. Or you could use `rails g migration AddAttachableToClips attachable:references{polymorphic}`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37429/discussion-between-the-mini-john-and-depa)

Answer (score 0):

I think that unless there's some reason they all must belong to the user, you can simplify this a lot by making better use of your `clip` model.

Change your relationships to this:

User.rb

```
has_many :clips, dependent: :destroy
```

Clip.rb

```
belongs_to :user
has_one :show
has_many :albums
```

Show.rb

```
belongs_to :clip
```

Album.rb

```
belongs_to :clip
```

You can see the show by using `clip.show` and the albums by using `clip.albums` - individual albums can be called by using `clip.albums.find(params[:id])`

Comment: They must belong to a User. User's can create albums and a Show. They can edit the album etc.

Comment: sorry maybe i worded that poorly...they will still belong to a given user through this arrangement - because `clip` is actually `User.clips.find(x)`.  so when something `belongs_to` a clip, it automatically is in relationship to a given user

Comment: Oh cool, so Problem #1 should be solved. But how can i set up the Uploading. Meaning that when a user uploads a clip, how can he attach it to a specific album (Because there will be many) or to his show ?

Comment: For a user to add a clip to an album, the album should already be there, so maybe i misunderstood the original question.  don't `clips` actually belong_to each `album` and `show`?

Comment: Problem #1 is the associations which you explained. Problem #2 is how to assign a clip to a specific album or Show. The clips belong to album's and a Show, but not to Each. Either a album, or a Show. How can the user select where he want to assign the clip ?

Comment: I just mean I think maybe you should rethink your logic - any given `album` is filled with `clips` - and a `show` is also filled with `clips` - so really `clips` belong to either a `show` or an `album`

Comment: But how do i get the user to upload clips INTO the album without the clips controller. I guess you are right. I will rewrite my models with the associations so Clips belong to albums and shows. But my burning problem is HOW to upload clips to Albums OR Shows.

Comment: `Album` is a model and so is `show` - just create `clips` using nested resources during the new action - and if you want to create new clips for a previously existing album or show, make a static page that allows users to choose which album/show to add to - where the album/show they choose directs to the `edit` path for the given album or show.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37418/discussion-between-the-mini-john-and-dax)