# How to make a form for three models with many-to-many relations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

What's the best way to create a form for models with many-to-many relations?

### In detail:

I have 3 models: User, Task, TaskAssignment:

---

**User Model**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base   
  has_many :task_assignments
  has_many :tasks, through: :task_assignments
end
```

---

**Task Model**

```
class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :task_assignments
  has_many :users, through: :task_assignments
end
```

---

**TaskAssignment Model (Join Table)**

I can't use `has_and_belongs_to_many`, because I need additional fields in the TaskAssignment Model.

```
class TaskAssignment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :task
  belongs_to :user
end
```

---

By creating a new task, there should be the possibility to assign multiple users to a task, so I made this form view:

**Task Edit Form View**

```
<%= form_for(@task) do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :note %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :note %>
  </div>

  <select name="task[users]" size="5" multiple>
    <% @users.each do |user| %>
      <option value="<%= user.id %>"><%= user.email %></option>
    <% end %>
  </select>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

---

Now, I wonder how to go on in my controller:

**Task Controller**

```
  def create
    @task = Task.new(task_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @task.save
        format.html { redirect_to @task, notice: 'Task was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @task }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @task.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

---

I think I have to do something like that:

```
@task = Task.new(task_params)
users = ???
@task.users << users
```

---

1. Is that the way n:m data should be saved or are there any other magic rails functions?
2. How do i get the data from the select-box? I tried to receive them by setting the name of the select-box to `name="task[users]"`, but the variable `task_params` contains only the `note`-field

Comment: Oh boy i had the same problem. Take a look at my question and study the  voted answer -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18801881/many-to-many-connection-and-associations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a helper called [`accepts_nested_attributes_for`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html#label-One-to-many) that allows a parent object to create and update its nested objects. In this case, you want `Task` to be able to create and update `TaskAssignment`

First, allow `Task` to accept attributes for its kids and to assign attributes to them.

```
class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :task_assignments
  has_many :users, through: :task_assignments

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :task_assignments
end
```

That should point you in the right direction. Creating the form will look something like explained in [`fields_for` for one-to-many](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-fields_for-label-One-to-many).

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to save your object in any special way. Just remember to allow `:user_ids => []` in your `task_params`.

Also, your life might be a bit easier with the form helper [`collection_select`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/collection_select).

```
<%= f.collection_select :user_ids, @users, :id, :email, {}, { :multiple => true, :size => 5 } %>
```